# Initializing all ng-model from controller on load Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I am stuck into a problem where I am suppose to get all the **ng-models** which are declared as `ng-model="a['keyX']` and **initialize** them to `0` before the user starts giving inputs..

Due to some reasons I cannot use `ng-value`.

I tried to get `$scope.a` into my `initializeToZero()` function. It returns an empty json object.

I even tried using `$scope.$apply()` but my bad luck.

All I get is only an empty json object.

Is there any way I can initialize them all in the controller irrespective to number of inputs and keys?

The names of keys would be all different... I just provided generic key names here... So make sure that you do not hard code it.

I have mentioned `ng-controller` for the snippet but I am using `ui.router`

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  

    initializeToZero();

    function initializeToZero() {
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log($scope.a);
      } else {
        
        setTimeout(initializeToZero, 1000);
      }
    }



  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="a = {}">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key1']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key2']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key3']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key4']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key5']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key6']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key7']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key8']">


</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call initializeToZero in ng-init, and put "a = {}" as first line in initializeToZero function?
Or call initializeToZero in angular.element(document).ready function?

Comment: Yes I tried that.. It didn't work either.. @RicardoPontual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Cracked it... A bit of dirty coding has to be done.. But its alright.. here is the code..

```
function application(){
        $('input[ng-model^="a"]').each(function(){
            $(this).val(0);
        }); 
}

$scope.initializeToZero = function(){
    console.log("Called initializeToZero");
    if(!$scope.$$phase)
    {
        $scope.$apply(application);
        console.log("Applied");
    }
    else{
        console.log("REDOING");
        setTimeout($scope.initializeToZero,1000);
    }

}    
$scope.initializeToZero();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's a good practice to use a.key1 instead of a['key1']. Secondly, if you want to assign zero to all a values, then use the map function at the start of your controller:

$scope.a.map(function(item) { return '0'; });

That will return a with all items set to zero.

Comment: It didn't work for me... however you can edit and upload a code snippet to explain your point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your data is loaded before you display the input fields:

```
HTML:
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="getValues()">
 <div ng-show="dataLoaded">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key1']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key2']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key3']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key4']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key5']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key6']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key7']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key8']">
 </div>
</div>


IN YOUR CONTROLLER:
$scope.getValues= function () {
 // Do your initialization here
 // For example:
 angular.forEach($scope.a, function(key, value){
  $scope.a[key] = 0;
 })
 // Set dataLoaded to true
 $scope.dataLoaded = true;
}
```

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/KrmgNL?editors=1011

Comment: Read the question again.. The name of key is not fixed.. You have hard coded it...@gianni

Comment: Not enough... The inputs would be stuck on html along with ng-models

Answer (score 0):

you should first defined the function `initializeToZero`

js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $parse) {

    $scope.a = {};

    $scope.initializeToZero = function() {
     var temp = "key";
     for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
     var count = i + 1;
     var model = temp + count;
     var result = $parse(model);
     result.assign($scope.a, 0);
     console.log($scope.a);
 } 
}   

      $scope.initializeToZero();         

  });
```

html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key1">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key2">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key3">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key4">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key5">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key6">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key7">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a.key8">


</div>
```

Comment: $scope.a is suppose to be a json object and not an array.

Comment: it would be great if you could only console all the keys.

Comment: @TirthrajBarot, sorry, i have update it to json object and assign it value, please have a try!

Comment: @TirthrajBarot i have updated the code once more, pls check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116089/discussion-between-vino-dang-and-tirthraj-barot).

Comment: You don't need to put the intializeToZero function on the scope object. It's a local JS function to the controller. Not used anywhere in the view.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sort of a hacky way, but I guess it'll get the job done.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key1']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key2']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['key3']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['some']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['other']">
  <input type="number" ng-model="a['keys']">
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  $scope.a = {};
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    $scope.a[inputs[i].getAttribute('ng-model').replace(/^a\[\'(.*)\'\]$/, '$1')] = 0;
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rb969qwL/3/)

Comment: You hard-coded it to length 8.. It should be dynamic

Comment: You can loop through `<input type="number"`

Comment: @TirthrajBarot I figure getting the number of inputs is pretty trivial, and wasn't the core of the problem you were experiencing, so I didn't bother with it. I've edited my answer.

Comment: nope... Check the question again.. I have mentioned that the solution should be such that number of keys may be dynamic and the names would also be dynamic... its not just an array of keys from 1 to 8... Its different @LawrenceWebDev

Comment: @TirthrajBarot Do you have control over how the `<input>` elements are generated? Or are they stuck as the form `<input type="number" ng-model="a['anykey']">`

Comment: exactly.. They are stuck as you mentioned... @LawrenceWebDev

Comment: @TirthrajBarot Okay, so I changed my solution to iterate through the inputs and initialize any keys using a regular expression. Just take out the `ng-init="a = {}"` in the `<div>` and it should work.

Comment: I am getting this error : angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null